# Offline Number Gossip

Tags: offline, math

[Number Gossip](http://www.numbergossip.com) is a website that allows you to enter a number and it gives you some properties of that number. For instance, `42` is a Cake, Catalan, and Pronic number. It is pretty simple task and *'What is special about this number'* seems like a common question (e.g. origins of [Smith](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Smith_number) and [Taxicab](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Taxicab) numbers) so does there exist software that does this locally on your computer?

#### Requirements

- Works offline
- Takes a positive integer
- Shows sequences containing that integer

  - e.g. *'13 is a Fibonacci number'*
- Shows properties of that integer

  - e.g. *'13 is prime'*
- Linux or Windows

**Preferred**

- Linux [Debian]
- Command line tool
- Open source

#### Goal

Ideally, I'd like to be able to pipe output into this command (from the terminal) and get a list of sequences/properties. Then be able to add/contribute sequences/properties that the software might be missing. However, anything that works offline and will show famous/novel/interesting sequences/properties of integers would be great!

For example:

```
Input                    Output
-----                    ------
echo 153 | cmd            Rare:
                            Triangle
                            Hexagon
                            Narcissistic
                          Uncommon:
                            Harshad
                          Common:
                            Odd
                            Evil
                            Deficient
                            Composite
                            McNugget
                            Egyptian
```

Comment: It is unlikely that such a program would dynamically test all of these properties for the given number, as it could take ages for some properties. So the program would probably use a static database. I started extracting such data from Wikidata: https://goo.gl/MaVjmQ